# How many knights are there?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, first-order-logic

[image]

I cannot deduce the solution. I cannot deduce a solution.
Consider the case in which Anne is a Knave.
If Anne answers "Yes", then they are not both knights. Berne might be a knight, or they might be a knave. If Anne answers "No", then they are both knights. But Anne is a knave, so this leads to a contradiction. Therefore if Anne is a Knave, she answers "Yes", and Berne is either a Knight or Knave.

Consider the case in which Anne is a Knight.
"Yes" indicates they're both knights.
"No" indicates that Berne is a "Knave".

An answer of "No" thus indicates one knight.
An answer of Yes indicates 2 Knights, 1 Knight, or 0 Knights.

This question can only be solved if Anne answered "No".
But we are not given Anne's answer.
As such we cannot discriminate between the options.

Comment: But then since you are told that Anne's answer settles the matter her response must be No.

Comment: I think from here, you just have to apply the assumption that the questioner is a "perfect logician" and "is clearly able to tell who is who" based on the answer.

Comment: Note:  what you write is confusing and (I think) inaccurate.  If Anne replies No that means that she is a Knight and her companion is a Knave.  In all other configurations she says Yes.

Comment: @lulu How is it inaccurate?

Comment: To be honest, I realised the answer as I typed the question out. But as I had already typed it out, I felt it would be a shame to scrap it, so I left it.

Comment: My error, I didn't understand your phrasing of the cases.  I think you have it right.

Comment: "This question can only be solved if Anne answered "No". But we are not given Anne's answer. As such we cannot discriminate between the options.""   Except we were told the logician was able to solve it.  She wouldn't have been able to solve it if Anne answer was Yes.  So it must be that Annes answer was No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Consider the case in which Anne is a Knave. If Anne answers "Yes", then they are not both knights.

Anne is lying, so it could be that either Bernie is a knight and she is a knave *or* they are both knaves.

> If Anne answers "No", then they are both knights. But Anne is a knave, so this leads to a contradiction.

Yup, so that will never happen. So if she responds "No" she is a knight and Bernie is a knave.

In essence, if she responds yes there is no way to tell how many there are. Thus, she responded "No". So there is 1 kinght and 1 knave.

Comment: To be honest, I realised the answer as I typed the question out. But as I had already typed it out, I felt it would be a shame to scrap it, so I left it.